# Temporary table was created in SQL Server but the table name was appended with extra characters

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I tried to create a temporary table in SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.

```
CREATE TABLE #test1 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    MyDate DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
    MyValue VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

The table was created and was put in the "Temporary Tables folder under System Database/tempdb/Temporary Tables. and the table name is

```
dbo.#test1__________________________________________________________0000000000A5
```

I have no idea how many underscore were there. Why was the name appended such long characters?

As a a result I couldn't use it.

Comment: you can use the temp table by simply using the table name #temp - the extra characters are added by sql server to ensure there are no name clashes for temp tables,  you do not need to use them

Comment: Each session (connection) can create temp tables with the same name. *Within* that session, the simple name suffices. In tempdb, the longer names are used to disambiguate them. Since local temp tables are only usable from within the session that created them, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: How did you try to use it? Are you trying to build a global temp table for many connections/for all users?

Comment: So far the only way I can select from tempdb is to specifically "USE temdb" and do not use "#" in front of the table name. In this way the temp db table is put under tempdb/Tables folder instead of the tempdb/Temporary Tables folder.

Answer (score 2):

As other users have already stated in comments, sql server appends id and underscore to a temp table. These ids in the end is unique for a particular connection.

For fun and knowledge, you may try creating a stored procedure that creates/alters/drop a temp table. Then run the stored procedure twice exec1, exec2 on the same procedure. You will see different temp tables with same name with underscore and different id’s.